# Spring MVC - Session - Request

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, session, request

I have a Spring MVC (3) Controller and I trying to put in the annotations but failed Heres my code outline

```
@Controller
public class SpringController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String myHandler(@RequestParam("id") String id) {

        //My RequestParm is able to do the job of request.getParameter("id") 

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("name","Mike") ;
        return "myFirstJsp";
    }

   @RequestMapping("/process")
   public String processHandler(@RequestParam("processId") String processId) {

      //do stuff
      String someName = session.getAttribute("name");
      return "result";
   }

}
```

Just for the sake of session object I have to declare HttpServletRequest and HttpSession.
Is there anyway we can have a solution with @nnotations.

Thanks!

Comment: Guys my RequestParam has a syntax error .Its missing a ")" so dont be concerned over that. Just FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you haven't, you should look at [this documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html) on SessionAttributes, to see if it is applicable for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare `HttpSession` or `HttpServletRequest` as arguments in your handler and they'll be automatically informed.

```
public String myHandler(@RequestParam("id") String id, HttpServletRequest request) { ... }
```

There are a lot of different arguments and results for handlers. You can see them [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah I see 'em but I am still unable to comprehend as to how to get the session object from the HttpServletRequest using annotations. If anyone can elucidate this that would be great!

Comment: You don't NEED annotations if you do it this way, why do you WANT them? @SessionAttributes, as @Raghuram says, or @Scope("session") are annotations related to web session, but they are probably unsuitable for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like using HttpSession and want something managed by Spring which also has more scope control you can use org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest:

```
public String myHandler(@RequestParam("id") String id, WebRequest request) {
    request.getAttribute("name", SCOPE_REQUEST);
    ... 
}
```